# debug_pipe throws error about invalid UTF-8

Tags: r, windows, encoding, rstudio

EDITED TO INCLUDE MORE INFORMATION:

When I use debug_pipe() from the magrittr package to debug a line of pipes, I get the following error:

```
Error in gregexpr(calltext, singleline, fixed = TRUE) :
    
    regular expression is invalid UTF-8

Error: INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'closure'
```

I am using RStudio on a Windows machine. Sys.getlocale says the encoding is German_Germany.1252. SessionInfo() prints:

> ```
> sessionInfo()
> R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows Server x64 (build 17763)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale:
> [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
> [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252
> ```

When I set the encoding to German_Germany_UTF-8, the error is no longer thrown. Reopening scripts with a UTF-8 encoding did not change anything. My scripts are saved as UTF-8 files (if I didn't forget to do this anywhere) and sourced with encoding = "UTF-8". Some of them contain special characters.

I am trying to understand why exactly this error is thrown by R. Why does the encoding of my machine matter for the debug_pipe() function whereas I am not receiving any other errors when executing my scripts? Is there anything else I can do besides setting the encoding to UTF-8? Are there any resources that explain how R deals with encodings besides those in the help functions?

Comment: You need to show us more information, e.g. what `sessionInfo()` prints, and what the `debug_pipe` function contains.  The one in `magrittr` is very simple; the line you're showing looks as if it's something more complicated (unless that's your code being shown).

Comment: Switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)…